# UL inside DIV breaks vertical alignment

Tags: css

Made 4 columns inside a footer that are equal widths.

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id='one'>
        <ul>
            <li>list item one</li>
            <li>list item two</li>
            <li>list item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='two'></div>
    <div id='three'></div>
    <div id='four'></div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 0;
}

footer div {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#one {
    background: red;
}

#two {
    background: green;
}

#three {
    background: yellow;
}

#four {
    background: blue;
}
```

Everything looks fine with four boxes of different colors spread evenly across the footer but after I added a ul, the first div now doesn't vertically align with the rest. I made sure to account for any user stylesheet styles but that didn't matter.

http://jsfiddle.net/5xduumae/

Comment: That is because you cannot have an inline-block element (which you have set your `<div>` elements to) containing a block-level child.

Comment: Any reason in particular you are not using floats?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5xduumae/4/ use float. and after that, make a clear.

Comment: @user3008011 vertical-alignment can be a reason if the containers will have variable heights

Comment: Floats totally fixed it. Thanks! No objections to using floats, just like to know why it was doing that. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian if you want to kno why this happen chek the answer of bryanp and my comment

Answer (score 4):

Just add `vertical-align:top` to `footer div` in the CSS.

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5xduumae/3/).

Comment: +1 Default value for vertical-align is baseline .... when you add text now it's the baseline to make the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left;` on footer div. Updated with a clear class inside.

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/5xduumae/5/)